# How can facebook Fan Page admin post

Tags: c#, facebook, post, admin

**I can do the installation, but on my own behalf as administrator of the facebook is sending does not share. what could be the problem? Asp.net I'm using facebook sdk

how you can administrator get access to the fan page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request["Code"] == null)
    {
       Response.Redirect(string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}", app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope)); 
    }
}

private void CheckAuthorization()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> tokens = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    string url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}&code={3}&client_secret={4}", app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope, Request["Code"], app_secret);

    HttpWebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

    using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

        string vals = reader.ReadToEnd();

        foreach (string token in vals.Split('&'))
        {
            tokens.Add(token.Substring(0, token.IndexOf("=")), token.Substring(token.IndexOf("=") + 1, token.Length - token.IndexOf("=") - 1));
        }
    }

    string access_token = tokens["access_token"];

    dynamic messagePost = new ExpandoObject();
    messagePost.access_token = access_token;
    messagePost.picture = "picture";
    messagePost.link = "link";
    messagePost.name = "name";
    messagePost.caption = "caption";
    messagePost.description = "description ";

    FacebookClient app = new FacebookClient(access_token);
    app.Post("/PAGE ID/feed", messagePost);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/getting-started#get_token
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/publishing

As documentation says, you need to have special page token

1. Your application must have 'manage_pages' permissions to your user
2. Get page token (not your User token!)

   `GET https://graph.facebook.com/{page-id}?fields=access_token`
3. Also you can show all pages, what current user can manage.

   `GET https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me/accounts?access_token=#{user_token}`

will return something like:

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "access_token": "EAACEdEose0cBACZBQs59Xjr....",
      "category": "Community",
      "name": "xxx",
      "id": "111",
      "perms": [
        "ADMINISTER",
        "EDIT_PROFILE",
        "BASIC_ADMIN"
      ]
    },
    {
      "access_token": "EAACEdEose0cBAPRKAgY.....FOr",
      "category": "Magazine",
      "name": "xxx",
      "id": "111",
      "perms": [    
        "CREATE_CONTENT",
        "MODERATE_CONTENT",
      ]
    },
```